# Bug nos caracteres do terminal de saída do VS Code

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-code, ide

No meu terminal de saída as letras com acento e o "Ç" são substituídos por interrogação, alguém sabe como resolvo isso?

Exemplo:

```
Compila��o com �xito.
    0 Aviso(s)
    0 Erro(s)
```

Answer (score 1):

Para resolver modifique manualmente a [configuração](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/settings) do terminal do VSCode.

```
"terminal.integrated.shellArgs.windows": ["/k", "chcp 850"]
```

Comment: Se não der certo de um retorno, eu não uso o VSCode. A informação eu tirei da web e adaptei para codepage pt-br(850).

Comment: Não resolveu, eu uso o bash como terminal padrão com esse código mudaria o terminal padrão, o meu erro ocorre no terminal de saída.

Comment: @MárcioSebastião dentro do `tasks.json` modifique  "command": "cmd",
"args": ["/c chcp 850 >nul && mingw32-make"]

Comment: Agradeço muito sua ajuda, mas ainda não resolveu, ocorreu que meu terminal foi trocado e o de saída ainda com o mesmo bug